# SQL Server cannot execute query

Tags: sql, ssms

When I try to execute any query in sql server, I get this error message many times:

> Cannot execute script - Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpC9BA.tmp' because it is being used by another process. (mscorlib)".

I then have to click ok and run the query again and it will work fine.

Comment: Please remove mysql tag.  This is an MS SQL-SErver specific question.

Comment: It sounds like SQL Server needs to use that ***.tmp file, but it's locked. Are you able to manually delete that file? It might remove the lock error 

Comment: Its a SSMS issue not an SQL Server issue.

Comment: What @AlexK. said: SQL Server is fine, your local installation is screwed. This isn't necessarily a bug in Management Studio; it could also be (for example) an overactive virus scanner keeping temporary files locked. In any case, don't expect many other people with this problem. Restart SSMS, reboot, and if it persists, reinstall, in that order.

Comment: can you share what the script does or is it for all queries

Comment: you also can fire process explorer from sysinternals to see what is the other process

Comment: it happens for all queries

Answer (score 0):

Mscorlib is actually .net dll, but I faced such file locking issue due to my antivirus sometime back. Could be an issue for u too.

Comment: My anti-virus is Mcafee. I can't uninstall my anti-virus.

Answer (score -1):

It seems there is an answer to this over at SQL Server Central:
[Check your anti-virus](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1818419/Management-Studio-cannot-execute-a-query)

Here's the main part of the answer there for future reference:
"
This sounds a lot like an Anti-Virus problem.

It's unlikely that two processes would use the same temp file name - and especially to keep doing it.

I suppose it's also possible that you have an Add-in or extension in SSMS that is somehow locking the file - try making sure you have removed any and test again.

Another thing to try is open Resource Monitor, go to the CPU tab, then search the Associated Handles section for .tmp to see if you can spot it. "

Comment: it seems the link is dead

Comment: not sure about what is said in the link. I have many softwares installed. How to know which one may be causing the issue?

Comment: I would start with anit virus.  You say your's is McAfee ... make sure you add to its exclusions that directory path.